# dedekind cut correspond to one and only one real number

Tags: analysis

Essays on the Theory of Numbers---Dedekind

> Whenever, then, we have to do with a cut ($A_1, A_2$)
> produced by no rational number, we create a new, an
> **irrational number** $\pmb a$, which we regard as completely
> defined by this cut ($A_1, A_2$); we shall say that the
> number $\pmb a$ corresponds to this cut, or that it produces
> this cut. From now on, therefore, **to every definite
> cut there corresponds a definite rational or irrational
> number**

Here Dedekind defined what irrational numbers is.  I think this conclusion is based on the assumption that $^*$ ***there exists at least one rational number between any two irrational numbers***. As it will certainly be a cut by two irrationals if no rationals exist in between. So shouldn't we prove  '$*$' first? But how could we prove if we havn't defined irrational number?

Comment: I suppose Dedekind presupposes the (intuitive) existence of the real numbers, to intuitively describe the meaning of a ‘cut’.

Comment: But you can make this rigorous if you already have constructed $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If we define there's only one real number corresponding to this cut, Then we could prove there exists at least one rational number between any two irrational numbers along with other properties of reals.  According to this, it's a well defined definition in my opinion. @Shinrin-Yoku